# Obtaining just the last row when using beautiful soup

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

import pandas as pd

def Get_Top_List_BR(url):
    
    
    response = requests.get(url)

    page = response.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

    table = soup.find(id='table')
   
    rows = [row for row in table.find_all('tr')]
    

    movies = {}

    for row in rows[1:]:
        items = row.find_all('td')
        link = items[1].find('a')
        title, url_string = link.text, link['href']
        #split url string into unique movie serial number
        url = url_string.split('?', 1)[0].split('t', 4)[-1].split('/', 1)[0]
        #set serial number as key to avoid duplication in any other category-especially title
        movies[url] = [url_string] +[i.text for i in items]
   
    movie_page = pd.DataFrame(movies).T  #transpose
    movie_page.columns = ['URL', 'Rank', 'Title', 'Genre', 'Budget', 'Running Time','Gross',
                    'Theaters', 'Total_Gross', 'Release_Date', 'Distributor', 'Estimated']

    return movie_page

df_test_BR = Get_Top_List_BR('https://www.boxofficemojo.com/year/2019/?grossesOption=calendarGrosses&area=BR/')

df_test_BR.head(10)
```

Problem: I am only getting the last row.
Question: How can I fix it to return all the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm not sure as to what Python version you are using but how you implement BeautifulSoup is incorrect, at least in my version. BeautifulSoup heavily recommends using a parser [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser). Your following code here:

```
 response = requests.get(url)
 page = response.text
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
 table = soup.find(id='table')
```

should be:

```
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find(id='table')
```

What your issue is how you define the url inside the for-loop. I managed to loop through all the elements, but how you define the `url` is specifically the issue. The way you read the define the `url` inside the for-loop **returns blankspace**.

So you say it returns just the last item. When it gets' to the last item, it'll fetch the url in the for-loop. But the url is just blankspace, and the key already exists in movies. Therefore, it'll overwrite the existing data there.

I'm not sure how you wanted the `url` defined, but this code does as you intend - fetch all the movies, their names, `href` values, and return the first 10. The only differences should be how you define `url` and `movies[url]`, but be careful not to trip up on the url again.

Also, the way you redefine `url` within the for-loop to represent a unique-ID should reflect that, as such - name it unique_id (or, in this example `uid`). I also included print statements to demonstrate it goes through the entire loop and also gets the first 10 values.

```
def Get_Top_List_GR(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find(id='table')
    rows = [row for row in table.find_all('tr')]

    movies = {}
    for row in rows[1:]:
        items = row.find_all('td')
        link = items[1].find('a')
        title, url_string = link.text, link['href']
        # split url string into unique movie serial number
        uid = url_string.split("/")[-2]
        print("{0} - {1} - {2}".format(url, title, uid))
        # set serial number as key to avoid duplication in any other category-        especially title
        movies[uid] = [url_string] + [i.text for i in items]
    movie_page = pd.DataFrame(movies).T  # transpose
    return movie_page

df_test_ = Get_Top_List_GR('https://www.boxofficemojo.com/year/2019/?grossesOption=calendarGrosses&area=BR/')
print(df_test_.head(10))
```